# Positioning image made with createElement Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have the following CSS code

```
#block {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url("images/back.png");
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I'm trying to create an image that is positioned in the middle of the block.

```
var imag = document.createElement("IMG");
imag.setAttribute("src", "images/player_blue.png");
block.appendChild(imag);
imag.style.left = block.clientWidth/2 + "px";
imag.style.top = block.clientHeight/2 + "px";
```

The image is currently displaying in the top left corner of the screen. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

you must add for `imag`:

```
style: position absolute
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to set [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) as [absolute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning)

```
#block {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url("images/back.png");
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

then

```
var imag = document.createElement("IMG");
imag.setAttribute("src", "images/player_blue.png");
block.appendChild(imag);
imag.style.left = block.clientWidth / 2 + "px";
imag.style.top = block.clientHeight / 2 + "px";
imag.style.position = 'absolute';
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lptj2dzw/)